# Responsive Progress Bar Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a responsive multi step progress bar, [link here](https://codepen.io/johnny_s/pen/QWyjNbq) and code snippet below;

```css
.multi-steps > li.is-active:before, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
  content: counter(stepNum);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active:after, .multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:after {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.multi-steps {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.multi-steps > li {
  counter-increment: stepNum;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  color: tomato;
}
.multi-steps > li:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  content: '\2713;';
  content: '\10003';
  content: '\10004';
  content: '\2713';
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.multi-steps > li:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.multi-steps > li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: tomato;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li {
  color: #808080;
}
.multi-steps > li.is-active ~ li:before {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <br /><br />
  <ul class="list-unstyled multi-steps">
    <li>Start</li>
    <li class="is-active">First Step</li>
    <li>Middle Stage</li>
    <li>Finish</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This works fine but on smaller screens (e.g max-device-width: 480px), portrait mode i'd like to stack the steps vertically.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your media query, change `display: table-cell` to `display: block` on the `.multi-steps > li` element. That should get you close to what you want to achieve. You'll also need to apply some additional styling just to neat it out.  Hope that helps.

e.g.

```
.multi-steps > li {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip on the `display: block;`, any other tips as to the "additional styling just to neat it out"?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<span>` element arounf the text, the use this CSS

```
.multi-steps > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.multi-steps > li:before {
    content: '\f00c';
    content: '\2713;';
    content: '\10003';
    content: '\10004';
    content: '\2713';
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: tomato;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.multi-steps > li:after {
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: tomato;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 3px;
    height: 105px;
}

.multi-steps > li span.step {
    margin-left: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```